# Git tells me my branch has no tracking information, but there is an older version of my branch on the remote

Tags: git, bitbucket

Some changes were committed to master by my colleague and I had to update my branch accordingly. After some struggling I thought I had gotten it right. However, when I run `git remote show origin`, I get:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://bitbucket.org/....git
  Push  URL: https://bitbucket.org/....git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    layout        tracked
    layout-report tracked
    master        tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    layout        pushes to layout        (fast-forwardable)
    layout-report pushes to layout-report (local out of date)
    master        pushes to master        (up to date)
```

The branch I'm trying to work on is `layout-report`, which says 'local out of date'. So I tried `git pull` and I get:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> layout-report
```

And on BitBucket I can see my branch. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

You may have pushed or pulled it using `git push origin branch`

Not having a tracking information just means that it's not specified where it should push to / pull from by default.

`git` is even telling you how you can set this (default) tracking information:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> layout-report
```

See [Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) in the git book.

Comment: Tracking information is unrelated to any information on any remote. It's just telling where you want to pull / push, if you do not specify an explicit remote for an operation.